# How to configure flutter with travis CI

Tags: flutter, travis-ci

I'm trying to configure my flutter application with travis-CI but I cant figure out a way to do that.

I tried my .travis.yaml file with following code

```
  - linux
sudo: false
addons:
  apt:
    # Flutter depends on /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 version GLIBCXX_3.4.18
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test # if we don't specify this, the libstdc++6 we get is the wrong version
    packages:
      - libstdc++6
      - fonts-droid-fallback
before_script:
  - git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b beta
  - ./flutter/bin/flutter doctor
script:
  - ./flutter/bin/flutter test
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.pub-cache
```

As I'm new to this travis-CI thing can you help me to get out from this problem.

Comment: Can you share the result?

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution recently, it is working, but I still can't really make it work with integration tests in a simple. Somehow I would have to install an Android or iOS emulator in a virtual machine I think. There are some hints for that inside the [Flutter samples](https://github.com/flutter/samples/blob/master/.travis.yml).

Anyway, here is something simple that works for me:

```
env:
  - FLUTTER_GITHUB="https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git"

language: dart

dart:
  - stable

dart_task:
  - dartfmt

install:
  - git clone $FLUTTER_GITHUB -b stable

script:
  - ./flutter/bin/flutter doctor
  - ./flutter/bin/flutter test
```

You could also replace the `install` and `script` with a `jobs` workflow:

```
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: Flutter Test
      language: dart
      os: linux
      install: git clone $FLUTTER_GITHUB -b stable
      before_script:
        - ./flutter/bin/flutter doctor
      script: 
        - ./flutter/bin/flutter test
```